# How to get total count income and outcome messages on Kafka or Zookeeper service via JMX?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, jmx

Need to get common metric about **Kafka** cluster via **JMX**, for example, get total income and outcome message on this service.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the JMX values yet? Have you not found this information?

Comment: I found a lot of information bat not sure that is correct, for example for the incoming message I can use **kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec,topic=<topic name>** and atribute Count  but for outcome message I can't find appropriate path

Comment: I know there is BytesOut, not sure about messages. https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html#broker-metrics